# Merge values in columns into one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have [a dataframe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15OU7SwaxqW4vds3E2uN-exPiXOQg2bMJmrGcxIYalaI/edit?usp=sharing) with columns and I'd like to group the ones starting with 'Answer' into one named 'Answers'. This column already exists, but around line 3061 there are no more values, I have to add them. I've tried that so far:

```
columns_with_answer = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Answer')]
df['Answers']= df.columns_with_answer.tolist()
```

But I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-399b932d5740> in <module>()
      1 columns_with_answer = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Answer')]
----> 2 df['Answers']= df.columns_with_answer.tolist()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'columns_with_answer'
```

So, with the sample data:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdefg'),'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4, np.nan],'Answer1':['a','b','d',np.nan,'d',np.nan,'f'],'Answer2':['a','b','d','e','h','d','k'],'Answer3':['a','b',np.nan,'d','r',np.nan, 'l'],'F':list('aaabbbc'),'Answers':['truc', 'machin', 'bidule', np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]  })
>>>df.head()
    A   B   Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 F   Answers
0   a   4   a   a   a   a   [truc]
1   b   5   b   b   b   a   [machin]
2   c   4   d   d   NaN a   [bidule]
3   d   5   NaN e   d   b   nan
4   e   5   d   h   r   b   nan
```

I would like to start from row 3 to get:

```
A   B   Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 F   Answers
0   a   4   a   a   a   a   [truc]
1   b   5   b   b   b   a   [machin]
2   c   4   d   d   NaN a   [bidule]
3   d   5   NaN e   d   b   [nan, e, d]
4   e   5   d   h   r   b   [d, h, r]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select values by list `[]` and then convert to numpy array before converting to list:

```
df['Answers']= df[columns_with_answer].to_numpy().tolist()
```

Or use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `regex` parameter and `^` for start of string:

```
df['Answers']= df.filter(regex='^Answer').to_numpy().tolist()
```

EDIT: For apply solution only for rows if `Answers` column is filled missing values use:

```
columns_with_answer = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Answer') and col != 'Answers']
mask = df['Answers'].isna()
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: Answers, dtype: bool

L = df.loc[mask, columns_with_answer].to_numpy().tolist()
df.loc[mask, 'Answers'] = pd.Series(L, index=df.index[mask])
print (df)
   A    B Answer1 Answer2 Answer3  F        Answers
0  a  4.0       a       a       a  a           truc
1  b  5.0       b       b       b  a         machin
2  c  4.0       d       d     NaN  a         bidule
3  d  5.0     NaN       e       d  b    [nan, e, d]
4  e  5.0       d       h       r  b      [d, h, r]
5  f  4.0     NaN       d     NaN  b  [nan, d, nan]
6  g  NaN       f       k       l  c      [f, k, l]
```

Comment: Many thanks ! And how can I start it at a very specific row? Like in the row where `Answers` starts to be empty?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - Not sure if understand, do you think avoid all missing values in lists?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - With real data is really hard test/verify solution, is possible change sample data like `df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'Answer1':['a','b','d',np.nan,'d',np.nan],
         'Answer2':['a','b','d','e','h','d'],
         'Answer3':['a','b',np.nan,'d','r',np.nan],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})` and add expected output? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear ! I meant most rows already have `Answers` column with the appropriate content, but around line 3061 the column is empty. So I wondered how I could start it from a very specific row, or when I notice it starts to be empty. Sure for your data, I'm starting right away

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica Hmmm, the best is use sample data in previous comment, mainly I am not sure what should be in column data before first empty val? Empty vals? empty lists? Something else? And whats happen if some misisng values later?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - thank you, only small question - it seems in row 8 in real data are first missing values in answers0, 1, 2..., so it means all data bellow are NANs ?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - Added solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry I just updated my question to be more clear, sorry for the inconvenience. What I meant to start the answer grouping from row 3 as the others alread had things in the column `Answers`

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - I think I understand, is possible copy Dataframe instead text for input sample data?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - So it means if misisng values in `Answers` column then need replace by list from answers columns?

Comment: Exactly, yes ! From Answer0, Answer1, ... until Answer{i} is empty

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - answer as edited. One idea, test if `nan` are missing values or strings `nan`, if misisng values use solution above, if not working because `nan`s are string try change `mask = df['Answers'].isna()` to `mask = df['Answers'].eq('nan')`